# Google Sheets: Exclude a Tab when Running a Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to scripts and am trying to insert each tab name into their own M1 cell which I would like to be triggered by onSelectionChange(e) as the tab names are constantly updating.

This is the only code I have found that seems to do what I need:

```
function changeName() {
  var key = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('M1').setValue(key);
}

function onSelectionChange(e) {
  changeName()
}
```

The only thing is, I need it to exclude the tab 'Class List' but for the life of me cannot work how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

I would like to mention the following two points:

1. Take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) which gives you information regarding the selection in the sheet.
2. to exclude a sheet you can add an `if` condition and run the code inside of it only if the sheet name of the active sheet is different from `Class List`.

### Solution:

```
function changeName(e) {
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet(); // active sheet
  const nas = as.getName(); // name of the active sheet
  if (nas !="Class List"){
    as.getRange('M1').setValue(nas);
  }
}

function onSelectionChange(e) {
  changeName(e);
}
```